# Catching the name from a function

Tags: c++, string, class, declaration, name-lookup

While trying to pass a value to a constructed,  I kept getting errors about that the  constructed can't accept the value, is that because of the main class ? :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Class GettingVal{
    public:
        GettingVal(string z){
            setName(z);
        }
        void setName(string x){
            name = x;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
}  
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  GettingVal Name("Hiiiiiii");
  std::cout << Name.getName();
}
```

Here is the error I get after compiling the project :

```
error: ‘Name’ was not declared in this scope
   std::cout << Name.getName();
```

Comment: I get a lot more errors than that, there's a lot of typos and use before declaration errors here: https://godbolt.org/z/8znqec

Comment: This code doesn't compile for multiple reasons.  `Class` instead of `class`, no `;` after class definition, `string` before the `using namespace std` statement, etc.

Comment: Please check you are copy pasting the actual code you are compiling

Comment: When you have many many errors fix the very very first error and recompile. If you want help here you need to give us one specific error to deal with - this is a bit too general.

Comment: If this is Visual Studio I recommend you look at the error messages in the Output tab and not the errors list for 2 reasons. 1. The errors in the Output Tab are always in proper order, 2. The error messages in the Output Tab are often in a more verbose format which sometimes helps. #1 is important because many times a single error could cause multiple problems.

Answer (score 4):

For starters there is a typo. There is a missed semicolon

```
Class GettingVal{
   //...
};
^^^
```

The standard class `std::string` is declared in the namespace `std`.
So you have to use either the qualified name `std::string` in the class definition or to use the using declaration

```
using std::string;
```

before the class definition.

And remove the redundant using directive

```
using namespace std;
```

The member functions of the class could be declared and defined the following way

```
    GettingVal( const std::string &z){
        setName(z);
    }
    void setName( const std::string &x){
        name = x;
    }
    const std::string & getName() const {
        return name;
    }
```

Though the constructor could be defined simpler

```
    GettingVal( const std::string &z) : name( z ){
    }
```